# How to redirect to a login page, but only when the browser is navigating to a page

Tags: http, http-headers, authorization

I'm writing an authentication/authorisation shim in front of my HTTP server, that will detect the lack of an authorisation token - either a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` field or an encrypted token in the cookie - and refuse to satisfy the request. This shim will intercept every request for a resource from the origin server (it's a Lambda@Edge function on a AWS CloudFront CDN, in front of static S3 content, for context).

In the case where the request was made because a user navigated to the URL, either by entering it in the browser or following a link, I want the response to cause a redirect to my authentication page (which will eventually return the user to the original URL, this time with an auth token). This is an OAuth2 flow, on a separate domain, the protected domain is not handling username/password entry.

In the case where the request was made by the browser simply loading a resource referenced by the page (for example an image embedded in the page, or Javascript / CSS files), I want to simply refuse with a 401/403 response as appropriate.

What I'm struggling with is how to identify, from the request headers, the difference between the two cases. Is there a canonical way to do this? It feels like the `Accept` header should be my guide in this, but I need this to work even if the user has entered the URL of an image resource into their browser (i.e. I can't just redirect only if `Accept` includes `text/html`). Or can I rely on the presence of `*/*` to indicate that this is a navigation request that doesn't know in advance what the `Content-Type` will be?

Or is this simply bad practice, for some reason I'm not seeing, and I should either always redirect or always refuse?

Comment: It turns out that even when loading embedded resources, such as images and JS files, the browser still sends `*/*` in the Accept header. Presumably this is because it's trying to be super generous about what it can handle rather than trying to describe all the possible content-types that would be viable, i.e. it can't just say `Accept: image` when the resource is referenced by an `<img>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of an answer that actually solves the problem, I thought I should reply with the answer that I've reluctantly settled on.

While it may be technically correct that lack of valid credentials should result in a 401/403 response for a resource, that's true of the navigation load as well. If you're responding with a 307 to redirect for auth, you're already subverting that expectation.

In practice, what matters is what the end user sees: when the browser tries to load an embedded resource but gets a 307 back, it goes and fetches the login form HTML page that it was redirected to. Because that's not an image resource (or whatever was expected), and because it's changed content type to something that might potentially be malicious, modern browsers block it on CORB grounds. I'm not sure what older browsers do, but I doubt they render HTML instead of the `img` or whatever element that the page specifies. The net result is the same in both cases - the user sees a broken link instead of the embedded resource.

Contrast that with the load that comes from a navigation action, where the browser **will** happily redirect and show the HTML login form, as intended. It might get a little squiffy if you've iframed the page that's going to redirect into another page, but we've already got `X-Frame-Options: DENY` in our login form for security reasons to make it refuse to work in that case.

So in the absence of a good way to do it "properly", you can simply choose to redirect in all cases, and you get an end result which is arguably fine. It would be much nicer if HTTP itself had a more graceful integration, like the ability to add a redirect in a 401/403 response and send the browser "somewhere else" to get a Bearer token back, but there's probably reasons I can't see why that is a bad idea.

Comment: 4xx codes is error codes so they cannot redirect user anywhere. And 307 or 301/302 redirections doesn't signal to client that there is any problem with authorization - it may be any kind of redirection (for example from HTTP to HTTPS or from one domain to another). For many authorization schemas (for example OpenID Connect and OAuth2) authorization requires requests to special authorization endpoint with additional parameters (for example clientID and scope) which are absent in usual request. So just redirecting to authorization page doesn't work for typical REST API.

Comment: And there may be non-browser clients such as mobile applications. They must know when to open browser for authorization. And the only method to know it is to check for 401/403 errors

Comment: This is fundamentally the problem, and it's an HTTP issue. 401/403 indicates to the browser that (new) credentials are required, but the only mechanism supported is popping up the basic auth username/password dialog box. You can return a `WWW-Authenticate` header to tell the browser the realm and type of credentials required, but that just alters that dialog box. The OAuth2 RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750 section 3) talks about how you have to use the Bearer scheme, but there is no mechanism where the server can say "redirect to page X to get those credentials."

Comment: Hypothetically, it would be nice to be able to say: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token expired", credentials_url="https://myloginserver.com/auth/login?state=nonce12345&response_type=code&redirect_url=https://protecteddomain.com/auth/callback"`

That doesn't have to be just for OAuth2, it just needs some common format for describing to the browser an action it can initiate to go fetch credentials.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% method to differ direct user request from automated browser request because they both are made by browser. But you can use several techniques.

1. First is to split your resources in 2 classes.

   - One class is html pages (usually they can be detected by resource name. For example by extension **.php**, **.aspx**, etc, or no extension at all). Users during their typical workflow usually request only html pages. These resources redirect unauthorized requests to authorization page.
   - Another class is all other resources (js, css, images, etc). They simply refuses all unauthorized requests with 401/403 code.
2. Second approach is to mark all automatically loading resources on your webpage with special mark (for example by adding query parameter to **uri** like `?auto=1`). And then all requests with such parameter will be considered as automatic. Resource marking is easiest during page generation on backend or frontend.
3. The third approach is extension for the first one. In addition we use [Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header of HTTP request. It identifies the address of the webpage which is linked to the resource being requested.

   - When user enters URL directly in browser address field `Referer` header is absent in request.
   - When browser make request of image, css, etc `Referer` contains URL of web page with this resource.
   - When user navigates between pages it contains URL of previous page.

So we can consider all web pages and images with empty `Referer` header as requested directly. And all resources (except web pages) with `Referer` - as automatic request.

Unfortunately `Referer` header is not reliable - browsers don't send this header sometimes for some reasons - [privacy policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Referer_header:_privacy_and_security_concerns), [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), etc. You can try it on your own risk.

Comment: Unfortunately, your first approach fails in the "I need this to work even if the user has entered the URL of an image resource into their browser" case.
It wasn't made clear in the question, but the second case won't work for me because in my case I am not in control of the server code, only the framework being used to serve; I can't require my developers to alter the way they generate the pages to satisfy the auth constraints here. The intent is to provide seamless auth / serving that their code is unaware of.

Comment: @MrCranky I understand your issues. I've added the third approach to my answer. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Definitely closer, but I think the fact it falls down on navigation between resources would be a deal breaker. Users will be following hyperlinks to resources on the domain, so `Referer` will probably be set more often than not. I think the fundamental thing I'm trying to capture here is the difference between a navigate (i.e. `window.location` has changed to point to a resource in this domain) and a load of an embedded resource. Thanks for the effort though, bounty awarded, and perhaps your answer will be of use to another user.